# Error in Flask Config Resulting in Site Refusing to Connect

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, ubuntu-18.04

I have setup Flask`Flask 1.1.2`  on NGINX `nginx/1.14.0` on Ubuntu 18.04 VPS.
The structure is-

```
myproject
       |--application
                    |-- app.py
                    |-- static
                             |--styles
                                    |--style.css
                    |--templates
                               |--index.html
```

I have followed the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploy-a-flask-application-to-ubuntu-18-04-server-69b414b10881).

To run I either do-

1)`export FLASK_APP=app.py` followed by `flask run`  or

2)`gunicorn3 --workers=3 application:app`.

When I do 1), it shows that Flask is running, but the browser(I have tried on 2 of them) show that the server refused to connect.
I then checked NGINX logs, but they also showed `connect() failed: Connection refused client:myip,server: 192.0.2.0 ,request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",host:serverip`.
Port 5000 has been allowed via `ufw`.

When I do 2), I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'`

app.py-

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

NGINX `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` (which has been disabled) is-

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.0.2.0;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

192.0.2.0 isn't my server ip.Also, port 8000 isn't open.

I haven't setup WSGI or anything(I have gunicorn).
It was working today morning, but now it suddenly started giving errors.
Also, I don't want it to be in development, but in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using gevent

```
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

http_server = WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 8000), app)  # ((STR(IP), PORT), flask object / app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```